# Python HTTP PUT on Local Network

Tags: python, json

I apologise if this is a stupid question, but I can't find any documentation to read on this. Currently, from my Windows machine, I send the following code to a bridge on my local network:

```
dump = [{
      "testdata"
      }]
r = requests.put("http://192.0.0.1", dump)
```

Instead, I wish to send this same code from the bridge to my Windows machine. I have no trouble sending it from the bridge, I am just unsure of how to receive it.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking here. What do you mean, you want to receive the information rather than send it? What is sending it, then?

Comment: Edited original post, sorry for being unclear.

Comment: And what is receiving this on a bridge? Standard web-server or some kind of Python listener?

Comment: Bridge is effectively a standard webserver

Answer (score 0):

On your Windows machine run a webserver too, on port 80, and listen for **PUT** requests. You can use Python's built-in HTTP server, there are many examples in the internet. Then parse the data and do whatever you want with them